# Is it ok to set the value of a different property in the setter of another property?

Tags: c#, oop, setter

I have two properties, the second depending on the first and I need to have both the properties in the class to be able to search them later.

My situation is that whenever property `A` is updated, property `B` should be updated too automatically i.e. Whenever someone changes the `Birthdate`, the `BirthDayAndMonth` should be updated automatically.

```
public class Example
{
    private DateTime? _birthdate;

    public DateTime? Birthdate
    {
        get => _birthdate;

        set
        {
            _birthdate = value;
            if (_birthdate != null)
            {
                BirthDayAndMonth = GetAnnualBirthday(_birthdate.Value.Month, _birthdate.Value.Day);
            }
        }
    }

    public Date? BirthDayAndMonth { get; private set; }
}
```

Does my code violate any OOPS principle?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that at all; it's (part of) what setters are for. I'd note though, that if somebody sets `Birthdate` to null, you'll want to set `BirthDayAndMonth` to null as well.

Comment: Sure, there's nothing wrong with that. If you didn't then you'd have to have `BirthDayAndMonth` compute its value every time it's called.

Comment: It's maybe personal taste but this example the second property is useless. It's just a view of the first property. Chances that you actually need that value as `Date` is probably between zero and never. Chances you need it as a string are very high and this is were string format come in.

Comment: An alternative I prefer: (assuming the logic in `GetAnnualBirthday` is simple) `public Date? BirthdayAndMonth { get { return GetAnnualBirthday(_birthdate.Value.Month, _birthdate.Value.Day); } }`

Comment: @MrAnderson, your code does not use encapsulation properly (you should use the getter), throws an exception when `_birthdate == null` and also forces the processing of GetAnnualBirthday() to however times BirthDayAndMonth is called.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti you're right I forgot the null-check. The advantage of this way is it's guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

No, your code does not violate any OOP principles. However, it can be made more efficient, despite this seeming to be doing rudimentary processing (obviously, depending on what `GetAnnualBirthday()` actually does).

I would *lazily* process it as per below. `Birthdate` can be changed many times in a row without having `GetAnnualBirthday` getting called, reducing processing. If and when `BirthDayAndMonth` is called, the `GetAnnualBirthday` is processed and the result saved for subsequent times.

```
public class Example
{
    private DateTime? _birthdate;
    private Date? _birthdateandmonth;

    public DateTime? Birthdate
    {
        get => _birthdate;

        set
        {
            _birthdate = value;
            _birthdateAndMonth = null; // force BirthDayAndMonth to be reprocessed
        }
    }

    public Date? BirthDayAndMonth
    {
        get
        {
            if (!Birthdate.HasValue)
                return null;
            if (!_birthdateandmonth.HasValue)
                _birthdateandmonth = GetAnnualBirthday(Birthdate.Value.Month, Birthdate.Value.Day);
            return _birthdateandmonth;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does my code violate any OOPS principle?

No.

The only problem I see with your code is thread-safety. For example, two threads are setting the value of `Birthdate`. One sets it to `null` while another thread sets it to something non-null. There can be a rare case where

```
if (_birthdate != null)
```

is true, then the next line,

```
BirthDayAndMonth = GetAnnualBirthday(_birthdate.Value.Month, _birthdate.Value.Day);
```

throws an exception because `_birthdate` is now `null`.

```
public class Example
{
    private DateTime? _birthdate;

    public DateTime? Birthdate
    {
        get => _birthdate;

        set
        {
            _birthdate = value;
            if (value != null)
            {
                BirthDayAndMonth = GetAnnualBirthday(value.Value.Month, value.Value.Day);
            }
        }
    }

    public Date? BirthDayAndMonth { get; private set; }
}
```

This guarantees thread-safety.